# How to get the range of t value in a Manipulate for trajectories?

Tags: equation-solving

How would I find the final time for different v and theta values so that the range of t in the manipulation would change for different v and theta values?

```
Column[Manipulate[
  Plot[{t ((v) Cos[θ]), (t ((v) Sin[θ]) - (0.5 (9.8) (t^2)))},
    {t, 0, ((2 (v) Sin[θ])/9.8)},
    PlotRange -> {0, 50}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"x(t)", "y(t)"}],
  {v, 0, 35}, {θ, 0, Pi/4}]]
```

Comment: Your code works if you change the `v` and `\[Theta]` ranges so they don't start at 0. Something like `{v, .1, 35}, {\[Theta], .1, Pi/4}`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly, you want the y plot range to be that of the height of the trajectory.

This can be achieved by noting that the max. height is reached when the derivative of the height is zero. Therefore the max height is:

```
tmax = t/.Solve[D[(t ((v) Sin[\[Theta]]) - (0.5 (9.8) (t^2))), t] == 0, 
    t][[1]];
hmax = (t ((v) Sin[\[Theta]]) - (0.5 (9.8) (t^2))) /. t -> tmax;
```

With this:

```
Manipulate[
 tmax = t /. 
   Solve[D[(t ((v) Sin[\[Theta]]) - (0.5 (9.8) (t^2))), t] == 0, 
     t][[1]];
 hmax = (t ((v) Sin[\[Theta]]) - (0.5 (9.8) (t^2))) /. t -> tmax;
 Plot[{t ((v) Cos[\[Theta]]), (t ((v) Sin[\[Theta]]) - (0.5 (9.8) \
(t^2)))}, {t, 0, ((2 (v) Sin[\[Theta]])/9.8)}, PlotRange -> {0, hmax},
   PlotLegends -> {"x(t)", "y(t)"}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, tmax}}], {v, 1, 35}, {\[Theta], 1, 
  Pi/4}]
```

[image]